# CPU Instruction in Containers

Tags: docker, cpu-architecture, singularity-container

I am not very familiar with container technology so maybe this question doesn't even make sense, but I am wondering if software compiled inside a container like Docker or Singularity can take advantage of particular CPU instruction sets like SSE4.1 or AVX2. So if a program was compiled in a container with a flag enabling AVX2 and the system on which the container was built supported AVX2, would the program error if the container was run on another system without AVX2 support? Can containers emulate CPU instruction sets?

Comment: The containerized process runs directly on the host kernel / hardware, so there is no difference between the cases when you run some stuff on the ordinary system or within the container. The process will use the same instruction set in both cases.

Comment: Ah so everything depends on the host hardware